# Excel - Writing a Complex Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following numbers in the range `AI3:AJ41`:

```
34  3
26  3
25  3
24  2
24  2
24  2
24  2
24  2
24  2
24  2
24  2
24  2
22  2
22  2
22  2
22  2
21  2
21  2
21  2
21  2
19  2
19  2
19  2
19  2
19  2
19  2
19  2
19  2
17  2
17  2
17  2
15  2
15  2
15  2
15  2
12  1
12  1
12  1
12  1
```

The `AI` column contains values while the `AJ` column contains  the following formula in cell `AJ3`:

```
=ROUNDUP(AI3/12,0)
```

which spans down to `AI41`.

In cell `AJ2` I have the following sum formula

```
=SUM(AJ3:AJ41)
```

which results in 77.

I want to write a formula into cell `AI2`, to get the same result as I now have in `AJ2` without using the (helper) column `AJ` i.e. only using the values of the `AI` column.

Maybe it can be a VB macro to do is, i don't know...

I've provided a link to my [Sample File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1783moPPd4cPElL0-dbmlXXUjZdDNk47N) for easy copy/pasting.
Thank you for your time & help.

Comment: i wrote the numbers "1" in the cells, the formula shall work without these "1"s. we have only one row and we need to calculate from one row only.

Comment: Could you confirm that you want to get the result without the helper column 'AJ', directly from the column 'AI'? Or if not, explain a little more what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I think he means he only wants what's in Row 1.I may reword this question as (I think) it's an interesting theoretical question, but definitely unclear.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated November 27**

I'm still at an airport, and decided to do this problem a stab without VBA/UDF.

An Array function can get you what you want. Type this into your worksheet with CTL SHIFT ENTER for a non-vba solution:

`=SUM(ROUNDUP(COUNTIF(A1:AH1,">="&ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&MAX(A1:AH1),TRUE)))/12,0))`

You can [download XLSM file here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nlwSg3S3-04xiEWe9NM9m_u5gPUn8-Wm).

For anyone who ever wishes they could perform VBA "loops" in a regular Excel formula, this is a pretty good example of how to approach as this essentially "loops" through the range with a higher integer each time by using the `Row` and `Indirect` functions. [Chip Pearson's sight is brilliant for stuff like this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx).

**UPDATED Nov 26**

I am sitting bored in an airport, so I will give this another go... I think this custom function will get the OP what they want. Put this in anywhere and you'll get 77. `=UMutCustom2(A1:AH1)`

The custom function code needed is here:

```
Function UMutCustom2(rng As Range) As Double
Dim r As Long

For r = 1 To Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)

    UMutCustom2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, ">=" & r) / 12, 0) + UMutCustom2

Next r


End Function
```

**original Answer**

I included both of these examples [in a file here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nlwSg3S3-04xiEWe9NM9m_u5gPUn8-Wm).

Probably easiest to use an array formula. In cell Ai1 put this formula: `=SUM(ROUNDUP(AI3:AI999/12,0))`

However, after typing the formula ***YOU MUST HIT CTR SHIFT ENTER!***

This will create curly brackets around the formula so when you view the formula it should appear: `{=SUM(ROUNDUP(AI3:AI999/12,0))}` and does sum to 77 on my version of file.

(good news is that in 2019 Excel's new query [engine will not require the CTL SHIFT](https://www.excelcampus.com/functions/dynamic-array-formulas-spill-ranges/)!)

Alternatively, if you want to make a custom function using vba, you could use this custom function, that would not require ctr shift enter... here's VBA code to make that:

```
Function UMuTCustomFunc(rng As Range) As Double
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rCell As Range

    Set ws = Sheets(rng.Parent.Name)

    For Each rCell In Intersect(ws.UsedRange, rng).Cells
        UMuTCustomFunc = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(rCell.Value / 12, 0) + UMuTCustomFunc

    Next rCell

End Function
```

Comment: Nice VBA. I almost fell of my chair when I noticed how you created the reference to the worksheet: 'Set ws = Sheets(rng.Parent.Name)'. That's my today's headline. Beautiful.

Comment: thank you for your answer but i couldn't express exactly. delete the "1"s in the cells and try to write the formula.

Comment: @VBasic2008 yea it’s pretty useful and I use it almost religiously if I am running a loop on a range because a user will inevitably click an entire row or column, so I want to only check the intersect with sheets.usedrange or else it (usually) takes too long.

Comment: @UmutK your question makes no mention of deleting 1’s, not does any formula Excel formula ever delete any other cells data.... so not sure what you’re asking. Your question seemed pretty straight forward and you received 2 answers were very similar.

Comment: @UmutK, checkout the edited answer and if you download the same XLSM file you'll get what I think you're looking for.

Comment: @VBasic2008 hey here's a tip I learned not too long ago as an improved method to pull the worksheet of a range variable: `rng.Worksheet`  . A lot easier than `Sheets(rng.Parent.Name)` and technically less room for error if multiple workbooks with same sheet names happening. 

Comment: Unbelievable that you would show me this when I just saw it in an answer to a question where I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55092397/how-to-sort-every-row-individually-in-an-array-in-vba/55094112#55094112), too. Didn't give it a second thought, will definitely do now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## Sumproduct

If you don't want to use an array formula (too lazy to press `CTRL SHIFT ENTER`) you can use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ROUNDUP(AI$3:AI$41/12,0))
```

and press `ENTER`. The result is 77.

### Funny

I didn't even know there was a `ROUNDUP` function so I used this at first:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(MOD(AI3:AI41,12)=0,INT(AI3:AI41/12),INT(AI3:AI41/12)+1))
```

but it doesn't work without entering it as an array formula. This should serve as a reminder that even `SUMPRODUCT` won't always work as a 'non-array' formula.

### Addition

If you want to apply the same principle to the range `A1:AH1`, use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ROUNDUP($A1:$AH1/12,0))
```

The result is 87 though.

Comment: nice. I always forget about Sumproduct. I am keeping my answer up to offer different options, but I'll give you a tick and approve your edit to the question.

Comment: thank you for your time and support. i couldnt exactly write what i need. delete all "1"s and AI column and try to write the formula.