# How to sort every row individually in an array in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I constructed an array with the following code:

```
For i = 1 To Vehiclenumber
For j = 1 To Vendornumber
Worksheets("Vendor").Cells(i + 8, j + 4) = Worksheets("Shipment").Cells(i 
+ 13, j + 2).Value * Worksheets("Vendor").Cells(j + 1, 6)
Next j
Next i
```

And I had the following array (20 vehicles-5 vendor):

[image]

I want to sort the values for every row (for every vehicle) in descending order but without expanding the selection. So I want to take every row as an array and sort it. I am not even sure if it is possible.

Comment: So you want every Array element to consist of six columns ("Vehicle-Vendor" + 1 to 5)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below code to a module ...

```
Public Sub SortColumnsDescending()
    Dim rngData As Range, lngRow As Long, lngCol As Long, arrData() As Double
    Dim lngIndex As Long, i As Long
    Dim x As Long, lngMin As Long, lngMax As Long, strTemp As String

    Set rngData = Selection

    With rngData
        For lngRow = 1 To rngData.Rows.Count
            lngIndex = -1

            For lngCol = 1 To rngData.Columns.Count
                lngIndex = lngIndex + 1

                ReDim Preserve arrData(lngIndex)
                arrData(lngIndex) = rngData.Cells(lngRow, lngCol)
            Next

            lngMin = LBound(arrData)
            lngMax = UBound(arrData)

            For i = lngMin To lngMax - 1
                For x = i + 1 To lngMax
                    If arrData(i) > arrData(x) Then
                        strTemp = arrData(i)
                        arrData(i) = arrData(x)
                        arrData(x) = strTemp
                    End If
                Next
            Next

            lngCol = 1

            For i = UBound(arrData) To 0 Step -1
                rngData.Cells(lngRow, lngCol) = arrData(i)
                lngCol = lngCol + 1
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

... and then select your data without headers (as shown below) and run the macro.  The screen shot shows the data AFTER it's sorted.

[image]

I hope that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

It would be straightforward to use the inbuilt Sort functionality, and just loop through the range:

```
Function SortRowRangeData(dataRow As Range)
With dataRow.Worksheet.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add2 Key:=dataRow, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending
    .SetRange dataRow
    .Header = xlNo
    .Orientation = xlLeftToRight

    .Apply
End With
End Function

Sub test()
    Dim rRow As Range
    'I hardcode for test below, but you can calc & put in your data range(no headers or Vehicle column)
    For Each rRow In Sheet1.Range("B2:F11").Rows
        SortRowRangeData rRow
    Next rRow
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

## Sort Range

### The Code

```
Sub SortRowsDescending()

    Const cSheet As String = "Sheet1"   ' Source/Target Worksheet Name
    Const cRange As String = "B2:F21"   ' Source/Target Range Address
    Const cOrder As Long = 2            ' 1-xlAscending, 2-xlDescending
    Const cOrient As Long = 2           ' 1-xlColumns, 2-xlRows

    Dim rng As Range  ' Row Range
    Dim i As Long     ' Row Counter

    ' In Source/Target Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet).Range(cRange)
        ' Loop through rows of Source/Target Range
        For i = 1 To .Rows.Count
            ' Create a reference to Row Range.
            Set rng = .Cells(i, 1).Resize(, .Columns.Count)
            ' Sort Row Range in descending order.
            rng.Sort Key1:=rng.Cells(1), Order1:=cOrder, Orientation:=cOrient
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

### No Constants Version

```
Sub SortRowsDescendingNoConstants()

    Dim rng As Range  ' Row Range
    Dim i As Long     ' Row Counter

    ' In Source/Target Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:F21")
        ' Loop through rows of Source/Target Range
        For i = 1 To .Rows.Count
            ' Create a reference to Row Range.
            Set rng = .Cells(i, 1).Resize(, .Columns.Count)
            ' Sort Row Range in descending order.
            rng.Sort Key1:=rng.Cells(1), Order1:=2, Orientation:=2
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That there might be a difference is the only mystery, as the ENUMs are identical: `xlSortColumns = xlTopToBottom = 1` and `xlSortRows = xlLeftToRight = 2`

Comment: @Asger: Thanks, your absolutely right. My mistake happened because I was using a RAND formula to generate values, and I forgot to copy/paste values.